# How to load i18next translation on Framework7 ajax loaded page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

I am using i18next jquery version to localize the text in my framework7 code. It works on each file if I click the button to change language (using localstorage to save the language option). But If I load another file in the view for example about page, it doesn't work.

I am a newbie to javascript, I have done this using tutorials and other help.

How I can apply the translation to every page loaded in the view without the need of cilcking the button to change it?

Here is my i18next function with translation (language.js):

```
var itemslang = {
    "en": {
        "translation": {
          /* MENU */
          "About-Framework7": "About-Framework7",
          "Welcome-to-Framework7": "Welcome-to-Framework7",
        }
    },
        "br": {
        "translation": {
          /* MENU */
          "About-Framework7": "Sobre o Framework7",
          "Welcome-to-Framework7": "Bem Vindo ao Framework7",
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var language = "en";
    if (localStorage.getItem("language") != null)
        language = localStorage.getItem("language");

    i18n.init({
        lng: language,
        resStore: itemslang,
        fallbackLng: "en"
    }, function(o) {
        $(document).i18n()
    }), $(".lang").click(function() {
        var o = $(this).attr("data-lang");

        localStorage.setItem("language", o);

        i18n.init({
            lng: o
        }, function(o) {
            $(document).i18n()
        })
    })
});
```

And here the buttons that change language:

```
<button class="lang en" data-lang="en">EN</button>
<button class="lang br" data-lang="br">BR</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

I forgot to load the file my-app.js in index.html

Which had the code for the translation work:

```
$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
  $(document).i18n();
});
```

This will apply the translation in every loaded view.